# Jbehave JunitStories and maven

Tags: java, maven, jbehave

I'm doing BDD using JBheave, but when I execute my tests with Maven, also if the test fails it says **BUILD SUCCESSFULL**.

How can I make it fail the build if something goes wront?

This is my test case configuration:

```
@Slf4j
public class JBehaveStoriesTest extends JUnitStories{

    @Override
    public Embedder configuredEmbedder() {
        final Embedder embedder = new Embedder();
        embedder.embedderControls()
            .useThreads(1)
            .doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
            .doIgnoreFailureInStories(false)
            .doIgnoreFailureInView(false)
            .doVerboseFailures(true);

        final Configuration configuration = configuration();

        embedder.useConfiguration(configuration);
        embedder.useStepsFactory(stepsFactory());

        return embedder;
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryLoader(
                new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())
            )
            .useFailureStrategy(new FailureStrategy() {

                @Override
                public void handleFailure(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
                    log.error("errore", throwable);
                    throw throwable;
                }
            })
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                new StoryReporterBuilder().withCodeLocation(
                    CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass())
                )   
                .withFormats(
                    Format.TXT,
                    Format.CONSOLE
                )
                .withFailureTrace(true)
            );
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new ProjectSteps());
    }

    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        List<String> s = new StoryFinder()
            .findPaths(
                "src/test/resources/",
                "**/*.story", 
                ""
            );
        return s;
    }
}
```

Googling my problem I found that someone says to call the **verify** phase after the **integration-test**. But for me doesn't work.

The problem is something related to the JBehave configuration I think, because also if I execute the test from Eclipse it is always successfull.

Another think I notice is that if I try to debug a Jbehave statement (a method marked with `@Given`, `@When` or `@Then`) the JVM doesn't stop and I can't entry the debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this fantastic extension https://github.com/codecentric/jbehave-junit-runner